Access a storage account with private link (public access disabled) on local machine with P2S VPN setup
I have created an Azure Storage account with a private link and disabled public access. I was able to connect to the storage account from a VM (on Azure) that didn't have public address.
I tried to setup the Virtual Network Gateway and configure P2S vpn. Did the VPN installation on my system and connected the VPN.
Then I tried connecting to the blob storage after connecting to VPN (thinking that I am in the same VNET as the storage private link) but I couldn't. I was greeted with the above screen.
Am I missing something? Is it possible to connect to private storage blob from local bench via VPN?

If you run nslookup stplazdoceastus.blob.core.windows.net in command prompt what does it return? In order for this to work, it needs to return the private endpoint's IP address. I'm suspecting it'll return the public address for you currently.

nslookup is currently returning the public IP. Let me try adding private Ip to the host file.
I messed up something with the VPN gateway, fixing that first. Will post an update after adding private IP in the host file.


Access a storage account with private link (public access disabled) on local machine with P2S VPN setup

If you are unable to access the storage account via VPN  there might be issue with DNS.
To resolve the issue, you can add a host entry on your local machine with the Private Endpoint IP and the Storage Endpoint.
10.0.0.5    venkatstoragetest1.blob.core.windows.net

To connect to a storage account via VPN while disabling public access, follow these steps to configure the VPN gateway.
I have configured storage account with Private endpoint.

Storage account Private Endpoint.

Private Endpoint Configuration

Private DNS Configuration

Private DNS Record Set

Vnet DNS Server Configuration

Storage account test result

After adding the host entry in the hosts file, it is resolving the Private Endpoint IP.

Test result

After configuring all the settings, I am able to access the storage account via VPN from local device.

Reference: Configure server settings for P2S VPN Gateway certificate authentication
